# Check filesystem only in area where seemingly corrupted file is

Tags: linux, filesystems

I get errors reading a large file, as in

```
# md5sum file
md5sum: file: Input/output error
```

Looking at the output of strace I see that the read() system call returns EIO, and in the corresponding manual page, it says, about EIO, that

> It may also occur when there is a low-level I/O error while reading from a disk or tape.

How can I check and fix the problem other than, possibly, running `fsck -c` on the huge filesystem where this file is?

Comment: If your hard drive is giving I/O errors, you really should check the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only two scenarios, which might give "Input/output error" on "md5sum file":

- The file system **structure** is defect (e.g. referencing a block beyond the fs size). In this case `fsck -c` is not necessary, a simple `fsck -f` should so the trick
- The storage medium itself is defective (e.g. the HDD). In this case, `fsck -c` will not be able to fix the issue, as it is not inside the fs's scope

My recommendation is to

- first run `fsck -f` to make sure it is not the first option
- first copy all readable files to a backup medium
- then use `ddrescue` to have a go at the files, that are unreadable in the first pass
- if this hows any error, destroy and dispose fo the drive

Comment: Very interesting!  So you say, it's either at filesystem level, or at hardware level.  I realize the error may be in other layers?  I mean, there's this fs on top of a logical volume, on top of software raid, on top of the hardware.  How can I rule out errors in the LVM or software RAID layer?

Comment: You can't. The main point is, that MD or LVM errors are 1. very unlikely and 2. will not easily lead to "Input/output error" but something more exotic. Let me also clarify what I mean with "storage medium": Everything below the point where control passes from the block device to the driver.

Comment: Thank you Eugen.  In my case, in the end, the software raid got messed up.  A device disappeared (`blkid` didn't show it).  I rebooted and re-added such device to the array, and after rebuilding, all was fine.  For the moment.  I'll keep an eye on this.